# Meaning of Conditional sentences with 'should' and 'happen to'

Tags: conditional-constructions

I'm a bit familarized with conditional sentences. But the following sentences with 'should' and 'happen to' are quite confusing too me. They are:

1. If it should rain, I will stay at home.
   2.If it should happen to rain, I'll stay at home

   3. If it happens to rain, I'll stay at home.

What are the meaings of those sentences ? Do they all mean the same ?
Thank you a lot in Advance for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

They all mean the same. If it should rain... = If it rains...

'should' is slightly more formal.

Comment: I'm afraid to say that I'm also asking about the meaning of each sentences. . . Which you'v not included. It would be better if i could get detailed answer of my question.

Comment: I'm asking the meanings and difference of those sentences

Comment: @yubrajsharma They all mean : If, by any chance, it rains...

Comment: If so, why there are different sentence structure ? Should, should happen to and happen to

Comment: I'm not satisfied with that answer

Comment: @yubrajsharma I don't what your mother tongue is, but I can tell you that in English and Greek, there are often several ways to say the same thing, with no difference in meaning or intent. 'should' is more formal, as I said.